# Scheduling job with liferay 6.1

Tags: java, liferay-6, job-scheduling

I am referencing this link [link](http://proliferay.com/liferay-quartz-scheduler/)

to schedule my job with liferay.

i have added Job Scheduler class which is :-

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.Message;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListener;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListenerException;

public class SchedulerLiferay implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void receive(Message arg0) throws MessageListenerException {
        System.out.println("hello world");

    }

}
```

on my liferay portlet.xml file i have added:-

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>quartz-demo</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <scheduler-entry>
            <scheduler-event-listener-class>com.infinite.npsc.Job.SchedulerLiferay</scheduler-event-listener-class>
            <trigger>
                <!-- <simple>
                    <simple-trigger-value>
                        5
                    </simple-trigger-value>
                    <time-unit>second</time-unit>
                </simple> -->
                <cron>
                    <cron-trigger-value>0/5 * * * * ?</cron-trigger-value>
                </cron>
            </trigger>
        </scheduler-entry>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
        <css-class-wrapper>quartz-demo-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
    </portlet>
```

and i also added this portlet on my **portlet.xml**  file like this:-

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>quartz-demo</portlet-name>
        <display-name>Quartz Demo</display-name>
        <portlet-class>com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>view-template</name>
            <value>/view.jsp</value>
        </init-param>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>Quartz Demo</title>
            <short-title>Quartz Demo</short-title>
            <keywords>Quartz Demo</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>
```

Job won't run. application starts successfully but nothing happens. i expect to print `hello world` in the console every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a working portlet based on your question, it is displaying "hello world" every 5 seconds in my console (on Liferay EE 6.1.30).

Let me send you the detailed steps:

1. I have used Liferay Developer Studio 1.6.3 to develop a new scheduler portlet for Liferay 6.1
2. Within Developer Studio, I clicked on File -> New -> Liferay Project
3. As "Liferay Portal Runtime" environment I used my portal extracted from: liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1-ee-ga3-sp5-20160201142343123.zip
4. Within my project, I clicked on File -> New -> Liferay portlet and accepted default settings (note: I would avoid using characters like '-' in portlet or class names)
5. Then I created a new class 'SchedulerLiferay' within my project, it looks identical to yours

:

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.Message;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListener;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListenerException;
public class SchedulerLiferay implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void receive(Message arg0) throws MessageListenerException {
    System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

6. Then I modified liferay-portlet.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE liferay-portlet-app PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Portlet Application 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_1_0.dtd">

    <liferay-portlet-app>
        <portlet>
            <portlet-name>quartz-demo</portlet-name>
            <icon>/icon.png</icon>
            <scheduler-entry> 
                 <scheduler-event-listener-class>com.test.SchedulerLiferay</scheduler-event-listener-class> 
                 <trigger> 
                   <simple> 
                      <simple-trigger-value>5</simple-trigger-value>  
                      <time-unit>second</time-unit>   
                   </simple> 
                 </trigger> 
            </scheduler-entry>  
            <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
            <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
            <css-class-wrapper>quartz-demo-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
        </portlet>
        <portlet>
            <portlet-name>quartzdemo</portlet-name>
            <icon>/icon.png</icon>
            <instanceable>false</instanceable>
            <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
            <footer-portlet-javascript>
                /js/main.js
            </footer-portlet-javascript>
            <css-class-wrapper>quartzdemo-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
        </portlet>
        <role-mapper>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
            <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
        </role-mapper>
        <role-mapper>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
            <role-link>Guest</role-link>
        </role-mapper>
        <role-mapper>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
            <role-link>Power User</role-link>
        </role-mapper>
        <role-mapper>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
            <role-link>User</role-link>
        </role-mapper>
    </liferay-portlet-app>
```

**Note:** I believe 'simple trigger' and 'cron' should not be used together.
This may be the reason why it didn't work at your side.

7. I modified my portlet.xml by defining my class name in the portlet-class tag:
   com.test.QuartzDemo
8. In case you run into this issue:
   "Queueing QuartzDemo-portlet for deploy because it is missing portal-compat-hook"
   The solution is described here:
   https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/27738413
9. I deployed my portlet
   At this point you might run into the ecj.jar issue, which can be solved by:

   1. Go to Window> Preferences> Ant> Runtime > Classpath
   2. Add External jar (ex : E:\liferayliferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.0-ce-ga1-20120106155615760\lib\ecj.jar) , i.e. ecj.jar located under your plugin sdk folder.
   3. Now Re-run the build script

Make sure to use a 1.6 compliant JVM.

At step 6 we need to take special care, to fill out this tag with the correct class name:
com.test.SchedulerLiferay

You can find the source code of the portlet here:
https://github.com/peterpetrekanics/QuartzDemo-portlet-6130

In case you have any questions feel free to post it here,
Best Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

The Liferay Cron Scheduler is a bit sensitive and does not accept every value.

You can use this one to execute the job every minute:

```
0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *
```

On http://www.cronmaker.com/ you cat get a expression that is accepted by Liferay.